# Parsley.js minlength not firing

Tags: parsley.js

I've got the following code in a simple min length test with parsley.js.  The form validates the 'required' parameter on the input tag but does not generate a message when a single character (below the minlength value of 6 per the parameter) is entered and form is submitted.  The JS alert fires on the submit button click. Thanks for your feedback in advance!

```
<html>
<body>
    <form data-validate="parsley" parsley-validate>
        <input type="text" id="parsley-minlength" parsley-minlength="6" placeholder="minlength = 6" required="required" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="mytestbutton" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/parsley.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('#mytestbutton').submit(function()
    {
        alert('validating');
        $('#parsley-minlength').parsley('validate');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/HAvq5/ Do you see any errors in your console? Maybe the path to `/parsley` is incorrect?

Comment: Thanks.  Your fiddle works great.  When I copy it into my fiddle with the same settings, I don't get the minlength validation.  Exact same code produces different results.  http://jsfiddle.net/ricktig/Hq696/

Comment: You don't have parsley loaded in the external resources ;) Add http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/1.2.2/parsley.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `"data-parsley-minlength"="[6]"` to your tag. Or use `.addError` method [description here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-javascript)

Comment: From [Built-in validators](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#validators), shouldn't it be `data-parsley-minlength="6"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
  <input id="password" type="password" data-parsley-minlength="6"   id="password" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Enter password" required>
```